# mysql crashing on queries to some tables

Tags: mysql, linux, server

We are running mariadb 10.3.25:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.25-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

It seems that there is some sort of corruption in some of our databases’ tables.

Exhibit A:

```
MariaDB [etherpad]> select * from store;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

In the meantime, this happens in the log:

```
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: 2021-01-16 19:51:52 0x7f0c884b8700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in file /build/mariadb-10.3-RRxkin/mariadb-10.3-10.3.25/storage/innobase/row/row0sel.cc line 2972
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: InnoDB: Failing assertion: prebuilt->trx->isolation_level == TRX_ISO_READ_UNCOMMITTED
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: InnoDB: [...]
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: 210116 19:51:52 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: [...]
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: Server version: 10.3.25-MariaDB-0+deb10u1-log
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: key_buffer_size=16777216
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: read_buffer_size=131072
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: key_buffer_size=16777216                                                                                                                                                                          [55/647]
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: read_buffer_size=131072
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: max_used_connections=16
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: max_threads=153
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: thread_count=22
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: It is possible that mysqld could use up to
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 352736 K  bytes of memory
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: Thread pointer: 0x7f0c500093b8
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: terribly wrong...
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: stack_bottom = 0x7f0c884b7dd8 thread_stack 0x30000
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x563337b2b05e]
Jan 16 19:51:52 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x54d)[0x56333765e09d]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12730)[0x7f0c91ef1730]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x10b)[0x7f0c914ae7bb]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x121)[0x7f0c91499535]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4e3433)[0x5633373a2433]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4d5d6c)[0x563337394d6c]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x9d8814)[0x563337897814]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x9dcdcf)[0x56333789bdcf]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x918681)[0x5633377d7681]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler11ha_rnd_nextEPh+0x127)[0x563337662db7]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13rr_sequentialP11READ_RECORD+0x1c)[0x56333776a43c]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10sub_selectP4JOINP13st_join_tableb+0x1e3)[0x5633374bdf03]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN10exec_innerEv+0xaaa)[0x5633374e01ba]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x33)[0x5633374e03d3]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_selectP3THDP10TABLE_LISTjR4ListI4ItemEPS4_jP8st_orderS9_S7_S9_yP13select_resultP18st_select_lex_unitP13st_select_lex+0xef)[0x5633374deaaf]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13handle_selectP3THDP3LEXP13select_resultm+0x14d)[0x5633374df38d]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5c1d8c)[0x563337480d8c]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x5857)[0x56333748d087]
Jan 16 19:51:53 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_statebb+0x1c9)[0x56333748f879]
Jan 16 19:51:54 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcjbb+0x111d)[0x56333749172d]
Jan 16 19:51:54 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x122)[0x563337492e82]
Jan 16 19:51:54 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP7CONNECT+0x23a)[0x5633375641ba]
Jan 16 19:51:54 hostname mysqld[31236]: /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x3d)[0x56333756433d]
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7fa3)[0x7f0c91ee6fa3]
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f)[0x7f0c915704cf]
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Trying to get some variables.
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Query (0x7f0c50012e20): select * from store
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Connection ID (thread ID): 733
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Status: NOT_KILLED
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,de
rived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_joi
n_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_d
erived=on,split_materialized=on
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Writing a core file...
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Resource Limits:
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes                                                                                                                          [0/647]
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max processes             15390                15390                processes
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max open files            65536                65536                files
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max pending signals       15390                15390                signals
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max nice priority         0                    0
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max realtime priority     0                    0
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
Jan 16 19:51:55 hostname mysqld[31236]: Core pattern: core
Jan 16 19:52:02 hostname mysqld[6672]: [... innodb crash recovery ...]
```

---

A very similar thing happens with some other tables as well.
What I tried:

- I wanted to dump all data, purge the entire mariadb installation and restore. Unsurprisingly, `mysqldump` runs into the same corruption (?) and the database crashes during the dump.
- I tried following a guide that advises to create a MyISAM table and fill that with data from the innodb table, but this fails for the same reason.

**What can be done about this? Naturally, we need the data in these tables. It appears that once the query hits a certain record/block (I am oblivious to inner workings of mysql) it crashes the server. So how do we salvage the data?**

---

**UPDATE 2021-01-18** as requested, here are the `variables` and `status` queries:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show global variables like '%thread%';
+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                     |
+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| aria_repair_threads                     | 1                         |
| binlog_optimize_thread_scheduling       | ON                        |
| debug_no_thread_alarm                   | OFF                       |
| innodb_encryption_threads               | 0                         |
| innodb_purge_threads                    | 4                         |
| innodb_read_io_threads                  | 4                         |
| innodb_thread_concurrency               | 0                         |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay               | 10000                     |
| innodb_write_io_threads                 | 4                         |
| max_delayed_threads                     | 20                        |
| max_insert_delayed_threads              | 20                        |
| myisam_repair_threads                   | 1                         |
| performance_schema_max_thread_classes   | 50                        |
| performance_schema_max_thread_instances | -1                        |
| slave_domain_parallel_threads           | 0                         |
| slave_parallel_threads                  | 0                         |
| thread_cache_size                       | 8                         |
| thread_concurrency                      | 10                        |
| thread_handling                         | one-thread-per-connection |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout                | 60                        |
| thread_pool_max_threads                 | 65536                     |
| thread_pool_oversubscribe               | 3                         |
| thread_pool_prio_kickup_timer           | 1000                      |
| thread_pool_priority                    | auto                      |
| thread_pool_size                        | 1                         |
| thread_pool_stall_limit                 | 500                       |
| thread_stack                            | 196608                    |
| wsrep_slave_threads                     | 1                         |
+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+
28 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show global status like '%thread%';
+------------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                            | Value |
+------------------------------------------+-------+
| Delayed_insert_threads                   | 0     |
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost   | 0     |
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost | 0     |
| Slow_launch_threads                      | 0     |
| Threadpool_idle_threads                  | 0     |
| Threadpool_threads                       | 0     |
| Threads_cached                           | 7     |
| Threads_connected                        | 12    |
| Threads_created                          | 98    |
| Threads_running                          | 6     |
| wsrep_applier_thread_count               | 0     |
| wsrep_rollbacker_thread_count            | 0     |
| wsrep_thread_count                       | 0     |
+------------------------------------------+-------+
13 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show global variables like '%timeout%';
+---------------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                         | Value    |
+---------------------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout                       | 10       |
| deadlock_timeout_long                 | 50000000 |
| deadlock_timeout_short                | 10000    |
| delayed_insert_timeout                | 300      |
| idle_readonly_transaction_timeout     | 0        |
| idle_transaction_timeout              | 0        |
| idle_write_transaction_timeout        | 0        |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout           | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout              | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout            | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout                   | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout                     | 86400    |
| net_read_timeout                      | 600      |
| net_write_timeout                     | 600      |
| rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout          | 10000    |
| rpl_semi_sync_slave_kill_conn_timeout | 5        |
| slave_net_timeout                     | 60       |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout              | 60       |
| wait_timeout                          | 28800    |
+---------------------------------------+----------+
19 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show global status like '%timeout%';
+-------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                       | Value |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
| Binlog_group_commit_trigger_timeout | 0     |
| Master_gtid_wait_timeouts           | 0     |
| Ssl_default_timeout                 | 0     |
| Ssl_session_cache_timeouts          | 0     |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show global status like '%aborted%';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| Aborted_clients  | 3     |
| Aborted_connects | 0     |
+------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

The server has **5 GB** of RAM.

---

About the `store` table:

```
MariaDB [etherpad]> show create table store;
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| store | CREATE TABLE `store` (
  `key` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value` longtext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [etherpad]> select count(*) from store;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   779443 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1 min 19.378 sec)
```

---

Here is the `iostat` info:

```
$ iostat -xm 5 3
Linux 4.14.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 (hostname)      01/18/2021      _x86_64_        (1 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           8.63    2.39   16.53   22.68    0.23   49.54

Device            r/s     w/s     rMB/s     wMB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
xvdap2           7.67   37.91      0.07      0.67     0.13    37.91   1.67  50.00   16.35    2.54   0.05     9.40    18.01   4.35  19.82
xvdap1           0.51    1.25      0.00      0.01     0.02     0.07   3.58   5.64    7.52   27.01   0.03     4.15     4.24   1.63   0.29

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          18.51    2.21   15.49   55.33    0.40    8.05

Device            r/s     w/s     rMB/s     wMB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
xvdap2           4.00  157.80      0.02      1.53     0.00    71.00   0.00  31.03    5.80   55.33   7.93     4.00     9.92   4.37  70.72
xvdap1           0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           8.96    2.44   15.68   15.27    0.41   57.23

Device            r/s     w/s     rMB/s     wMB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
xvdap2           0.00   22.20      0.00      0.40     0.00    35.40   0.00  61.46    0.00   22.81   0.30     0.00    18.27   4.11   9.12
xvdap1           0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
```

---

**UPDATE 2021-01-24:** I tried to pinpoint the problem by quasy-bisecting the table with `limit` clauses and found that out of the ~800,000 records, every query that selects records after 663,187 crashes the DB. The few records preceding the 663,187. one contain seemingly mangled data, see below.

```
MariaDB [etherpad]> select * from store limit 663184, 1\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  key:
value:
                     f[Y
                                       f[팩
```

Does this not hint at data corruption? What could I do about the problem? Get rid of these records?

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag since your question isn't related to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Microsoft sql? Looks like mysql to me. Have you got bin logs enabled and regular backups?

Comment: Do you have blobs in the table?  If so, check the value of max_allowed_packet.  https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/es/system-variables/max_allowed_packet/

Comment: You appear to be thread starved within MySQL. Please post text results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%thread%'; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%'; and C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%'; and D) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%timeout%'; and E) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%aborted%'; and F) How much RAM is on your server?

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE store;    How many rows are in store?

Comment: @WilsonHauck thanks, I added the results of the queries you requested. Server has 5 GB of RAM. I also added more information about the `store` table.

Comment: Check output of below query `select (@@GLOBAL.KEY_BUFFER_SIZE + @@GLOBAL.INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE + @@GLOBAL.INNODB_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE + @@GLOBAL.INNODB_ADDITIONAL_MEM_POOL_SIZE + @@GLOBAL.NET_BUFFER_LENGTH + (@@GLOBAL.SORT_BUFFER_SIZE +  @@GLOBAL.READ_BUFFER_SIZE + @@GLOBAL.JOIN_BUFFER_SIZE + @@GLOBAL.READ_RND_BUFFER_SIZE) * @@GLOBAL.MAX_CONNECTIONS)/1024/1024/1024 AS TOTAL_MEMORY_SIZE_gb\G`

Comment: `TOTAL_MEMORY_SIZE_gb: 0.668350219727` (I removed the deprecated `INNODB_ADDITIONAL_MEM_POOL_SIZE` sys var)

Comment: @bp99-novin Please post TEXT results from OS Command Prompt run  iostat -xm 5 3 and press enter.  For information, including core count, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I am not sure what you mean exactly by ‘TEXT results’, but I have added the output of `iostat -xm 5 3` to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the information available at this time, consider in your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G  # to use 40% of available RAM
REMOVE thread_cache_size to allow default sizing (or set it to 256)
REMOVE thread_stack to allow default calc of slightly larger thread_stack per ref man
```

When we know number of cores/cpus we may be able to provide additional suggestions.

When more than 1 cpu's are available, additional suggestions could be provided.

Your query: select count(*) from store;
may complete in less than a minute if your tried
SELECT COUNT(key) FROM store;
to only cause reading of the index, rather than every row.

Have a GREAT 2021.

Comment: Unfortunately, these changes to the config did not improve the situation. `mariadb` crashes the same way. Don’t you think there is some data corruption behind this?

Comment: I added more info my question: I kind of managed to find which records break the queries. Could you please take a look?

Comment: @bp99-novin  What is the result of SELECT @@thread_cache_size from MySQL Command Prompt?  Do you have flexibility to use Skype Talk?  I will be available in about 3 hours.  My Skype ID is wlhauck@aol.com  in Birmingham, AL  UTC -6 hrs.